# How can I trace JS while using Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, build

I want to gdb JS to see the change in Firefox while parsing JS, so I set `--enable-debug` while building Firefox, but it seems to be of no effect.

So, is there any other way to set the JS engine in Firefox in debug mode while buiding? And how?

Comment: What? You built Firefox just to debug your Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

use firebug, which is a very powerful develop tool for web app

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
console.log( 'Message ' or Object or Array or any data type )
```

It will work on most browsers in some way. For Chrome, it just works, for Firefox, you need Firebug. You can see it by opening the JavaScript Console.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug your JavaScript, to use the developer console for your browser. Often times this is accessed by pressing F12 on your keyboard(If you have downloaded firebug already). Otherwise click on Tools>Add-ons and download firebug and check console or script to debug.